# ContextMenu doesn't keep focus when using keyboard shortcut with JavaFX

Tags: java, windows, javafx, contextmenu

I have an application written in JavaFX using a TreeView, the ContextMenu depends on the selected TreeItem, my TreeCell implementation uses setOnContextMenuRequested() to show the ContextMenu whenever I right click on a node, this works fine. I want now to achieve the same when navigating the tree with the keyboard and using the standard shortcut for the context menu on Windows (SHIFT+F10), I almost managed to do it, it displays the ContextMenu but when I try to use the navigation keys to select an item in the menu it displays the context menu of the main application windows and navigates in it, also I would like to display the context menu close to the selected cell, how can I do that? Below is a small application that exhibits my problem

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.ContextMenuEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.PickResult;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
    try
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        TreeItem<String> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>("Root");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            TreeItem<String> child = new TreeItem<>("Item " + i);
            child.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>("Item " + i + "A"), new TreeItem<>("Item " + i + "B"));
            treeRoot.getChildren().add(child);
        }
        treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);

        root.setCenter(treeView);

        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            String text = "Choice " + i;
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(text);
            menuItem.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println(text));
            contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem);
        }

        treeView.addEventHandler(ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED, event ->
            {
                PickResult pickResult = event.getPickResult();

                if (pickResult != null && pickResult.getIntersectedNode() != null)
                {
                    TreeCell<String> cell = (TreeCell<String>) pickResult.getIntersectedNode();

                    Bounds bounds = cell.getBoundsInParent();
                    double x = bounds.getMinX() + (bounds.getWidth() / 2);
                    double y = bounds.getMinY() + (bounds.getHeight() / 2);
                    Point2D loc = cell.getParent().localToScreen(x, y);
                    contextMenu.show(cell, loc.getX(), loc.getY());
                }

            });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

KeenWrite's [MarkdownEditor](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/daf3453873f155afb47feca989e451ae80ab55b8/src/main/java/com/keenwrite/editors/markdown/MarkdownEditor.java#L62) class may be doing something similar. Instead of a `TreeCell` the program uses a `StyleClassedTextArea`, but the idea should transfer to other widgets:

1. Create the context menu.
2. Associate the context menu with the widget
3. Add menu items to the context menu.
4. Get the display bounds for the widget.
5. Force focus when the menu is shown.
6. Show the menu.

In code, this resembles:

```java
// The "text area" is analogous to the table cell widget.
final var textArea = getTextArea();
final var menu = new ContextMenu();

menu.setAutoHide( true );
menu.setHideOnEscape( true );
menu.setOnHidden( event -> textArea.setContextMenu( null ) );

final var items = menu.getItems();
textArea.setContextMenu( menu );

// Populate the menu items.
for( final var correction : suggestions ) {
  items.add( createSuggestedItem( caretWord, correction ) );
}

// Figure out the location of the table cell, and call
// menu.show with those X and Y coordinates.
textArea.getCaretBounds().ifPresent(
  bounds -> {
    menu.setOnShown( event -> menu.requestFocus() );
    menu.show( textArea, bounds.getCenterX(), bounds.getCenterY() );
  }
);
```

You'll need to tweak the code. That works for my purposes: the context menu appears, the first item is selected, the arrow keys can change the selected item, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> accepts the menu item.